# Reading an xml that contains errors in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlstreamreader

I have an xml that contains a lot of the same type of xmls.
I use DOM to read them.

My question is like this:
If I get an exception in reading one of the inside xml(like an extra "<" in a field),
how do I move to get the next xml?

The code is written in java using dom and XMLStreamReader

Comment: Could you provide a concise example and the exception you're getting?

Comment: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,26]
Message: Element type "null" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: What do you mean by saying you have "an xml" that contains "a lot of xmls"? Your terminology is wrong. The unit of parsing is an XML document. If an XML document is not well-formed, then you cannot extract anything usable from it.

Comment: e.g. <results><Person><age>6</age><Year>2013</Year></Person><Person><age>7</age><Year>2010</Year></Person></results> and each person is the xml im trying to extract

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you combine DOM and XMLStreamReader